# How to determine the maximum number of threads?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am learning parallel programming. I use OpenMP with C++ and I want to understand how to determine the maximum number of parallel threads I can set on my laptop. In the documentation I found the function omp_get_max_threads(), but how can I make sure the return value is correct?

When I'm compiling this code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout << omp_get_max_threads() << "\n";
    
#pragma omp parallel 
        {

           
        }
        return 0;

}
```

Output is: 8

When this:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    
#pragma omp parallel 
        {
            cout << omp_get_max_threads();
           
        }
        return 0;

}
```

Output is: 88888888

Comment: _"but how can I make sure the return value is correct?"_ What do you mean? What makes you unsure about the result you get?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm edited my post, please, check it out

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't udnerstand why the output is not the same, when I'm put cout in different places

Comment: In the first program, you have 1 thread print the value "8". In the second program, you have 8 threads print the value "8", so that value prints 8 times.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you. But if my laptop max threads is 8, why when set another threads number, for example 10-20, why program is still working?

Comment: The number of threads that can be running can be (and often is, system wide) much greater than the number of concurrent threads available in the hardware.

Comment: @Eljay so how I can determine the number of concurrent threads aviable for me?

Comment: [std::thread::hardware_concurrency()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) ... but there is no assurance that your program will be scheduled by the operating system all the available threading cores for your task.  There could be another program also busily using all the available hardware threading cores, so they'd be in contention.

Comment: ***I want to understand how to determine the maximum number of parallel threads I can set on my laptop*** The answer will likely be several thousand regardless of the number of CPU cores or virtual cores and may be limited by the size of the stack (each thread typically has its own stack). However you don't want to use the maximum possible number of threads that your process can create.

Comment: The number of concurrent threads is limited by hardware.  The number of threads that can be scheduled is limited by the operating system, and is probably in the thousands.  Each scheduled thread will have its own stack.  Depending on your OS, the stack might be wired.  Regardless, wired or not, the number of available threads will at some point be limited by RAM, unless there is an OS cap that is hit first.

Comment: IMHO, more interesting than the max. possible number of threads is the _appropriate_ number of threads. That depends on a variety of things: Extra threads cost extra scheduling in the OS. A sleeping thread doesn't cost much. A full working thread may occupy a full CPU core. Having more threads with full load than available CPU cores still may work (slower), and it may make other applications slower as they have to share the queues for pending threads with your application which is overly possessiv. (The last is a lesson learnt from a sim. appl. with many threads I once wrote.) ;-)

Comment: `omp_get_max_threads()` is fine to determine the maximum number of threads available in OpenMP. [In OpenMP documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu112.html) you can read "The `omp_get_max_threads` routine returns an upper bound on the number of threads that could be used to form a new team if a parallel construct without a `num_threads` clause were encountered after execution returns from this routine."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to find out how many threads you are able to use. You can do this by calling `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`.